# Test the equality of multiple arguments with Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to test the equality of multiple args (i.e. it should return `True` if all args are equal and `False` if at least one argument differs).

As `numpy.equal` can only handle two arguments, I would have tried reduce but it, obviously, fails:

```
reduce(np.equal, (4, 4, 4)) # return False because...
reduce(np.equal, (True, 4)) # ... is False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.unique` to check if the length of unique items within your array is 1:

```
np.unique(array).size == 1
```

Or `np.all()` in order to check if all of the items are equal with one of your items (for example the first one):

```
np.all(array == array[0])
```

Demo:

```
>>> a = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1])
>>> b = np.array([1, 1, 1, 2])

>>> np.unique(a).size == 1
True
>>> np.unique(b).size == 1
False
>>> np.all(a==a[0])
True
>>> np.all(b==b[0])
False
```

Comment: In the second approach, you are not sure if the first element is different from others.

Comment: @Learner We just want to check if all items are equal or not.

Answer (score 1):

The [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package has a builtin function for this. Note that it also works on multidimensional arrays, ie you can use it to check if a stack of images are all identical, for instance.

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
npi.all_equal(array)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your args are floating point values the equality test can produce weird results due to round off errors. In this case you should use a more robust approach, for example [`numpy.allclose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html):

```
In [636]: x = [2./3., .2/.3]

In [637]: x
Out[637]: [0.6666666666666666, 0.6666666666666667]

In [638]: xarr = np.array(x)

In [639]: np.unique(xarr).size == 1
Out[639]: False

In [640]: np.all(xarr == xarr[0])
Out[640]: False

In [641]: reduce(np.allclose, x)
Out[641]: True
```

*Note:* Python 3 users will need to include the sentence `from functools import reduce` since `reduce` is no longer a built-in function in Python 3.

Comment: My args are integers but I will keep in mind your answer, it could probably be useful one day!